# Android: How to I test for bugs on a device I don't have?

Tags: android

I just finished my first Android app. I tested it in the emulator and on my personal device (Nexus 6p). Other folks are installing it and it's working for them. My dad, however, also gave it a try. He has a Samsung Galaxy S6 running 6.0.1, and the app crashes on startup for him.

My guess is it's something touchwiz related. The thing is, he's not the most technical person, as far as getting a logcat would go. So... what are my options to try and investigate this issue?

Comment: Connect your dad's phone into your PC then diagnose through your logcat. I could not think of any other way.

Comment: Using something like Fabric (Crashlytics module) you can get crash logs and other useful logs from users.

Comment: Maybe you should keep some old Android devices around for debugging.  And keep the older versions of the OS on them too.

Answer (score 0):

[Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) can help you to retrieve the stack trace and exceptions when your app crashes.

But if you want to test and fix before the deploy, another options is [Xamarin Test Cloud](https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud), it's a paid solution, but have a free-trial

[EDIT]

Searching in the internet, I found something similar to Xamarin Test Cloud, I personally have not tested this solution, but you can check it out.
[TestMunk](https://www.testmunk.com/), they have a free plan.

Answer (score 0):

This is an aspect of the extreme fragmentation of the Android ecosystem.  I've seen bugs that manifest only on a specific device from a specific carrier.  For example, at one point, Verizon broke `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` on one of their tablets, so that no app would ever receive it.  It had worked fine on an earlier firmware version.  Naturally, they refused to acknowledge the problem.  The same tablet model from T-Mobile never exhibited this issue.

This is why I don't trust the emulator.  It's fine for early testing, but you still need to test on the actual hardware that you intend to support.  There are online services that test your app on a wide variety of real devices to try to uncover the weird vendor-specific issues.  I've never used these services, so I can't recommend one.